# How to add animation in the pointer in my screen?

Tags: android

I want to add animation in my pointer(touch) in the screen.

In Android , there was show touches option in developer setting and when i enable that a circle is casted wherever i touch or swipe my screen . I want to change that circle and style my own style.

How can I achieve that?
I already tried custom view , animation , drawing methods but no-one worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Settings enables a special feature `(aka "binary/executable" in this special situation)` that displays a floating small View at the exact point where a Touch event is detected. If you want to do the same thing outside your Application/Activity you need
**(1) Root Permissions (2) Directly access to Touchscreen data and then (3) display a floating View where you want.**

Comment: There isn't any Magic behind the Touch "cursor" which you can enable in Dev Settings. It is just a floating View that a System APK (hidden inside Android core) shows when a touchscreen event is detected/raised. The System has free access to Touchscreen Hardware data (X and Y coords) and then it could listen for them every time it needs. A normal App cannot do that without Root Privileges but can listen for touchscreen events only on its own Views.

Comment: Then , How to get root access and make my view floating in every windows including lock screen and notification drawer.

Comment: This is stackoverflow.com and not solveallmyproblems.com....all these things suppose a minimum (maybe advanced) knowledge of the platform that is out of the purpose of a single Question of this thread. Please check online tutorials or examples about each point I wrote and you could achieve what you want.